# How are non-string literals evaluated in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

When checking out the length property on a string I made a mistake and forgot the quotes around `length`. Instead of an error, one of the characters appeared from the string.

```
const string = 'name'
s[length]
>> "a"
```

I have done other combinations and usually get the second letter returned. So is the word `length` being converted into a Boolean, which is then converted to a number? Or, is something else going on?

Update. this is all I did:

```
const a = [1,2,3]
>> undefined
a["length"]
>> 3
const s = 'name'
>> undefined
s[length]
>> "a"
s['length']
>> 4
length
>> 1
a[length]
>> 2
```

Comment: Could you be using the variable `length` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: It was just in the console (Firefox), and I hadn't done much else.

Comment: Check it @SebastianSpeitel said because `("name")[undefined] = 'n'` because it cast undefined to `0`

Comment: What does console.log(length) give you?

Comment: But OP said it returns the second char

Comment: console.log(length)  gives me 0

Comment: andy you still get "a" and not "n"?

Comment: I'll paste in the full history...

Comment: `length == 1` which is why `s[length] == "a"`. @visibleman has the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the default scope, length will evaluate to [window.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length), which is the number of frames or iframes in the window (usually 0, but in your case maybe 1?)

Edit: A quick look at the meaning of the different examples in your updated question.

```
const a = [1,2,3]; // Array of length 3
a["length"];       // equals a.length , 3
const s = 'name';  // String of length 4
s[length];         // s[window.length], s[1], 'a'
s['length'];       // equals s.length, 4
length;            // equals window.length, 1
a[length]          // equals a[window.length], a[1] , 2
```

Comment: Good one!, Do you know other similar "shortcuts"?

Comment: @Naramsim, not entirely sure what you mean. In the 'default' or top level scope, this evaluates to 'window' which means that any property of 'window' can be accessed by it's short name, e.g. location points to window.location and so on

Comment: In the same manner, you can mostly use `setInterval` and don't have to use `window.setInterval`

Comment: @Naramsim: console.dir(window);

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a general piece of advice:

use `s.length` instead of `s['length']`

You avoid the mistake you just ran into.

I personally only use square brackets when I'm accessing values in a plain old array or when I need to use a variable or a property name that compilers don't like (ie. `s[myVar]` or `s['some-property']`).

Comment: Use the comment area for your valueable advice as this is the answer area.

Comment: He cant, I think, look at his reputation

Comment: Would if i could comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do `s.length` as length is property of String.

If you have `length` variable somewhere in your code, then it's typecasted to integer.

If you do not have it, then `undefined` is converted to integer.

---

`s[length]` converts to `s[0]` in your case

Comment: That's completely wrong. Bracket notation casts to String, not to integer (and there is not even an integer type in js...).